# How to set another Items Visible when Checkbox is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I have written a frame in java swing . In it I have a checkbox . I want , that after clicking checkbox others Item will change it visibility. I was trying to do it as in code below but is not working as i wish .

```
public InFrm() {
    setTitle("In");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
    seeMe=false;


    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
    splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.7);
    splitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
    getContentPane().add(splitPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    splitPane.setLeftComponent(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);


     JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    splitPane.setRightComponent(panel_1);

    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblKind= new JLabel("Kind");
    lblKind.setBounds(10, 8, 33, 14);
    lblKind.setVisible(seeMe);
    panel_1.add(lblKind);

    JComboBox ChoiceOd = new JComboBox();
    ChoiceOd.setBounds(53, 5, 28, 20);
    ChoiceOd.setVisible(seeMe);
    panel_1.add(ChoiceOd);


    // more items using seeMe


    JCheckBox chckbxOd = new JCheckBox("Od");
    chckbxOd.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
          seeOd();
          }
    });
    chckbxOd.setBounds(6, 150, 97, 23);
    panel.add(chckbxOd);



}

protected void seeOd() {
    if(seeMe){
        seeMe=false;
        }
    else
    {
        seeMe=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your see method you only set the flag but of course it does not set the visibility of your component. Set the visibility direct to the component, than it will work

Comment: Oh now i get what to do . But is it possible to pack all Items i want visible or not in something and changing state of the package so all disappear or appear visible ?

Comment: Since the flag is a primitive you can not have it like you want(reference), you have to iterate over all your boxes and set the flag for them

Answer (score 0):

Your Listener should look something like this:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
  Object item = ev.getItem();
  if (ev.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
    //hide the component associated with this item
  } else {
    //show the component associated with this item
  }
}
```